# RuntimeError: You need gevent installed to use this worker

Tags: python

I need gevent to run docker-registry but i have this error:

```
Error: class uri 'gevent' invalid or not found: 

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 139, in load_class
    mod = import_module('.'.join(components))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 22, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("You need gevent installed to use this worker.")
RuntimeError: You need gevent installed to use this worker.
]
```

I tried to install gevent with `apt-get` and `pip` but when run the command, have always this error

UPDATE:

Debian 7.8 64 bit

Output of `dpkg -l | grep python`

```
ii  libpython2.6                       2.6.8-1.1                     amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.6)
ii  libpython2.7                       2.7.3-6+deb7u2                amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
ii  python                             2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
ii  python-all                         2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          package depending on all supported Python runtime versions
ii  python-all-dev                     2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          package depending on all supported Python development packages
ii  python-apt                         0.8.8.2                       amd64        Python interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python-apt-common                  0.8.8.2                       all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python-chardet                     2.0.1-2                       all          universal character encoding detector
ii  python-debian                      0.1.21                        all          Python modules to work with Debian-related data formats
ii  python-debianbts                   1.11                          all          Python interface to Debian's Bug Tracking System
ii  python-dev                         2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          header files and a static library for Python (default)
ii  python-fpconst                     0.7.2-5                       all          Utilities for handling IEEE 754 floating point special values
ii  python-gevent                      0.13.6-1+nmu3                 amd64        gevent is a coroutine-based Python networking library
ii  python-greenlet                    0.3.1-2.5                     amd64        Lightweight in-process concurrent programming
ii  python-minimal                     2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          minimal subset of the Python language (default version)
ii  python-pip                         1.1-3                         all          alternative Python package installer
ii  python-pkg-resources               0.6.24-1                      all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
ii  python-reportbug                   6.4.4+deb7u1                  all          Python modules for interacting with bug tracking systems
ii  python-setuptools                  0.6.24-1                      all          Python Distutils Enhancements (setuptools compatibility)
ii  python-soappy                      0.12.0-4                      all          SOAP Support for Python
ii  python-support                     1.0.15                        all          automated rebuilding support for Python modules
ii  python2.6                          2.6.8-1.1                     amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.6)
ii  python2.6-dev                      2.6.8-1.1                     amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.6)
ii  python2.6-minimal                  2.6.8-1.1                     amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.6)
ii  python2.7                          2.7.3-6+deb7u2                amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
ii  python2.7-dev                      2.7.3-6+deb7u2                amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
ii  python2.7-minimal                  2.7.3-6+deb7u2                amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
```

Comment: What distribution? Looks like you might have a local installation of Python on your system. You don't want that unless absolutely necessary. Please paste the output of `dpkg -l | grep python` into your question, please.

Answer (score 11):

Just install Python gevent (in FreeBSD `pkg install py27-gevent` or 
`pip install gevent`).